# Check if the user exists in Firebase (phone auth)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I am writing an application on SwiftUI and Firebase. At the moment, I have implemented authentication by phone number. When a user enters a phone number, I get the phone number and id data in Firebase. But I also want to get a photo and a name from the user. I can implement this in a separate window. The problem is that if the user exits the application and logs in again, the application again asks him to upload a photo and write a name. Although the data about this user is already in Firebase. Is there a way after sending a message to check whether the user is registered or not to show or not to show an additional view with a photo and name request?

My function for sending code:

```
func sendCode() {
    
    self.isLoading.toggle()
    
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationId, error) in
        
        self.isLoading.toggle()
        
        if error != nil {
            self.isError.toggle()
            self.errorMsg = error?.localizedDescription ?? ""
            return
        }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationId, forKey: "verificationId")
        self.isVerify.toggle()
    }
}
```

My function for verification:

```
func verifyCode(code: String, name: String, num: String) {
    self.isLoadingVerify.toggle()
    
    let verificationId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "verificationId") ?? ""
    let credentials = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationId, verificationCode: code)
    
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials) { (authResult, error) in
       
        self.isLoadingVerify.toggle()
        self.userSession = authResult?.user
        self.fetchUser()
        
        if error != nil {
            self.isError.toggle()
            self.errorMsg = error?.localizedDescription ?? ""
            return
        }
        guard let user = authResult?.user else { return }
        self.tempCurrentUser = user
        
//        self.userSession = user
        
        let data = ["name": name.lowercased(),
                     "uid": user.uid,
                     "num": num
        ]
        COLLECTION_USERS.document(user.uid).setData(data) { _ in
              self.fetchUser()
//            self.userSession = user
//            self.fetchUser()убрал после того как не загрузилось фото профиля
        }

        print(authResult ?? "")
        self.isVerify.toggle()
        self.isVerified.toggle()
        self.isPhotoName.toggle()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you call signin, you can check if there is an already loggedin user.
Check:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser != nil
```

And you can avoid signing in again. If the user exists you can get user Id from

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I want to clarify more, I just started learning programming and I need some clarification.
In which part of the code should I insert Auth.auth().CurrentUser != null ? As I understand it, this call checks whether this user is in Firebase. But when I log in by phone number, I still have to send him a message and then use the code to make verification. Should I insert this code into the verification function? I mean, how do I use this call in practice, for example, to show or not to show an additional view after the user has entered the verification code? Thanks

Comment: For example, I ask if CurrentUser == nil, but it is equal to nil only until the user has typed the confirmation code from the sms. After all, it will not be nil immediately after the user has entered the code. Then it immediately becomes not nil even if it is logged in for the first time. @Seamus

Comment: The firebase SDK persists the logged in user to disk. This means after you login even if you restart the app completely when you open the app again you are still logged in, and do not need to verify the number again unless you call `Auth.auth().signOut()` somewhere. 
Think about how other apps like facebook work, you don't signin every time.

I would put the login check in your code before you call the `verifyCode(...`  so something like: `if isLoggedIn() == false { verifyCode() } else { // go to home screen)`

Comment: So, well, my user came in, made a profile, uploaded a photo and that's it. Then he takes another phone and wants to log into his account, enter your number, and then the program asks him again to write a name and upload a photo, but he has already done this. That's exactly what I would like to avoid. @Seamus

Comment: Yes on a different device this is a different scenario. If you verify the number again, you will get the same userId back from firebase. and you can use this id to fetch user information you previously saved. Probably you have saved some user details in a collection in a Firestore database ?  If so you need to get this information again after login.

Comment: If this answer helped you resolve the issue. Please accept the answer so it can also help others to resolve their issues in the future. Thanks/